# SQL- Using a value in one tuple to get a value from another one

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples

I have a table called employee which contains the following columns -

> Fname, Lname, ssn (primary key), salary, supervisor ssn, departmentname.

Now for each employee in the table belonging to the department 'Research', I want to output his name, salary and the NAME of his supervisor. What I currently have is this.

> SELECT fname, salary, superssn from employee where departmentname='Research';

Now this gives me only the ssn of the employee's supervisor, and not the supervisor's name. I know that I have to compare the superssn of an employee with another employee who has the same ssn and get that other employee's name since he's he supervisor, but I'm not sure how to implement this in the same command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a join back to the emplyee table (and you need an alias to reference that table), like this:

```
SELECT employee.fname, employee.salary, supervisorlist.fname as supervisor 
from employee 
left join employee as supervisorlist on supervisorlist.ssn = employee.supervisorssn
where employee.departmentname='Research';
```

Comment: Whoa, I have to admit that joining a table with ITSELF is something that never would have occured to me at all! Many thanks, I shall accept your answer as the best one in 9 minutes when it allows me to do so :D

Answer (score 1):

You need a self join:

```
SELECT researcher.fname, researcher.salary, supervisor.fname 
FROM employee researcher JOIN employee supervisor ON researcher.superssn = supervisor.ssn
WHERE researcher.departmentname='Research';
```

This gives you all related pairs from the cross product of employee x employee that match on the supervisor / researcher ssn.

When you want to include researchers without a supervisor, too, then you need a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: The other guy was first so I'll give him the best answer, but yours too is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :D